# Asymptotic behavior of integral with essential singularity

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I am interested in the integral $$I(h,a,b) = \sqrt{h} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} e^{-h u^2 -i(au -{b}/{u})}$$ as $h \to \infty$.

$a,b,h$ are all real parameters. Here the square root is defined for $u < 0$ as $\sqrt{u} = i\sqrt{-u}$.

I expect for $b=0$ the integral will blow up in the limit $h \to \infty$ like $\frac{(1-i)}{2}\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})h^\frac{1}{4}$ via a saddle-point style approximation.

I anticipate that for $b \neq 0$ the limit will be far more precarious (and $I$ may even dwindle to zero(!), which I see from numerics) as $h \to \infty$. I feel a little confused about how to handle behavior around the origin because of the essential singularity there.

For $b>0$, (and $a$ of either sign), what is the behavior of $I(h,a,b)$ as $h \to \infty$? In particular, what are the $a$ and $b$ dependences?

Comment: How do you define $u \mapsto \sqrt{u}$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: @Gary Thanks for checking for clarification. I've updated the question pointing out that I'm taking, for $u<0$,  $\sqrt{u} = i\sqrt{-u}$.

Comment: If it was $-h u$ in the exponential then one could write down a uniform asymptotics in terms of modified Bessel functions. With $u^2$ in place of $u$, the asymptotics should be in terms of some other special functions (generalised hypergeometric or Meijer-$G$ perhaps?).